# Codeigniter Hidden Form Becomes NULL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, codeigniter

I've got a really weird issue that I can't seem to figure out or understand. So essentially I have a to grab the ID passed through the Codeigniter URI, have it populate a hidden form, and then submitted. However when I submit the form as hidden, it comes back saying the data is NULL. I have tried and changed it to form_input and it works fine. Can anyone help me or explain to me why this is the case?

I have tried the following solutions.

**URL**

```
http://localhost/list/players/add/1/
```

where I want URI 3 ('1') to pass on to the form and submitted.

*Solution 1 - Having the URI pass straight to data array*

**Controller**

```
    function add() {

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                            $data['view_file'] = 'add';
                            $this->load->module('template');
                            $this->template->cmslayout($data);

                        } else {
                        $league_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

                        $data = array(
                            'leagues_id'  =>   $league_id,
                                     );

                       if($this->_insert($data)){
                            return $query;
                }
                redirect ('/players/');
            }
        }
```

*Solution 2 - Grabbing the URI and fill a hidden form*

**Controller**

```
    function add() {

        $league_id = $this->uri->segment(3);

        $this->load->module('leagues');
        $data['leagues_list'] = $this->leagues->get_where($league_id);

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

                            $data['view_file'] = 'add';
                            $this->load->module('template');
                            $this->template->cmslayout($data);

                        } else {

                        $data = array(
                            'leagues_id'  =>   $this->input->post('leagues_id'),
                                     );

                       if($this->_insert($data)){
                            return $query;
                }
                redirect ('/players/');
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
<?php
echo form_open('players/add/');
?>

<?php
echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

echo "League Name";
echo "<br>";
foreach ($leagues_list->result() as $row) {
    $league_id = $row->id;
    $league_name = $row->league_name;

    echo $league_name;

    $data = array(  'name'          =>      'leagues_id',
                    'value'         =>      $league_id,
    );
    echo form_hidden($data);
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";

$data = array(  'value'         =>      'Set Player',
    'name'          =>      'submit',
    'class'         =>      'submit-btn',
);
echo form_submit($data);

echo form_close();
?>
```

In both scenarios, on submit it comes back with an error saying leagues_id is NULL. Now I have tried in Solution 2 to change from 'form_hidden' to 'form_input' and straight away clicking submit and it works fine.

Can anyone help me or advise why this is the case?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a parameter to your controller's function, you have to add it to: `function func($parameter = 0)`  *(= 0 is optional for default value)*.
In this case you can access the parameter by `$parameter`.

In your View file, you can open your form to post to the current url. For this you need to load the url helper in your controller: `$this->load->helper('url');` (or you can autoload it in application/autoload.php).

Your form_hidden declaration was bad too. If you want to declare it with array(), then you have to use this syntax:

```
$data = array(
              'name'  => 'John Doe',
              'email' => 'john@example.com'
            );

echo form_hidden($data);

// Would produce:

<input type="hidden" name="name" value="John Doe" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="john@example.com" />
```

More information on Form helper: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

*For the right solution, try this:*

**Controller**

```
function add($league_id = 0)
{
    if($league_id != 0)
    {
        $this->load->module('leagues');
        $data['leagues_list'] = $this->leagues->get_where($league_id);

        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
           $data['view_file'] = 'add';
           $this->load->module('template');
           $this->template->cmslayout($data);
         }
         else
         {
            $data = array(
                'leagues_id'  =>   $this->input->post('leagues_id'),
            );
            if($this->_insert($data))
            {
               return $query;
            }

            redirect ('/players/');
        }
    }
```

**View**

```
<?php
echo form_open(current_url());
echo "<br /><br />";

echo "League Name <br />";
foreach ($leagues_list->result() as $row)
{
    $league_id = $row->id;
    $league_name = $row->league_name;

    echo $league_name;

    echo form_hidden('leagues_id', $league_id);
}

echo "<br /><br />";

$data = array(
    'value'         =>      'Set Player',
    'name'          =>      'submit',
    'class'         =>      'submit-btn'
);
echo form_submit($data);

echo form_close();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks skyyler. I've tried your solution however now it won't even load the next page when I submit (just a blank page). I've tried this with both form_hidden and form_input. Note in form_input, the form does populate with the correct ID, but now it won't even submit to database whereas previously it did.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to note that the 'url' helper is already autoloaded, and I don't understand what you mean by "your form_hidden declaration was bad too."? My syntax is exactly the same as the example provided, only difference is that it is in a foreach function so I can load the variables. Cheers.

Comment: I suppose that your `$league_id` don't get any value in this case (this is why you don't see anything after post). I don't want to change everything in your code, so please use your solution, but try the `form_hidden('leagues_id', $league_id);` instead of your `form_hidden($data)`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried changing the form_hidden to your suggestion as well. Still the same result.

Comment: No. Your form_hidden declaration is bad. This is your array: `$data = array('name' => 'leagues_id', 'value' => $league_id, );` The right declaration is: `$data = array('leagues_id' => $league_id);` The _array's key_ is the input name, and the _array's value_ is the value of the input.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the clarification and insight.

Comment: And if you use the Chrome developer functions, can you see your hidden field? (For developer functions press CTRL+SHIFT+I, or right click - Inspect element) If you can see it, and it has the right value, then your HTML code is okay, and the problem will be in the controller.

Comment: Looked at the developer function, found the issue and changed the declaration as you specified, and voila! Problem solved. Thanks mate!